# How to achieve Base64.getDecoder().decode(nonceBase64Encoded) in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, java, node.js, arraybuffer

I have some code written in java which I want to convert to JavaScript.

```
String nonceBase64Encoded = "+8GorZIWoF7mnZ2/M86/eA==";    
byte[] decodednoncebytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(nonceBase64Encoded);
```

About this decode():

> Decodes a Base64 encoded String into a newly-allocated byte arrayusing
> the Base64 encoding scheme.
>
> An invocation of this method has exactly the same effect as invoking
> decode(src.getBytes(StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1))

Comment: `atob()` doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The atob() function decodes a string of data which has been encoded
> using Base64 encoding. [read more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/atob)

example:

```
var decodedData = atob(encodedData);
```

> The btoa() method creates a Base64-encoded ASCII string from a binary
> string (i.e., a String object in which each character in the string is
> treated as a byte of binary data). [read more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/btoa)

example:

```
var encodedData = btoa(stringToEncode);
```

And if you want to convert strings into array of bytes then [`TextEncoder`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TextEncoder) can be used:

```js
new TextEncoder().encode(str)
```

Alternatively this function could be used:

```
function stringToByteArray(s){

    // Otherwise, fall back to 7-bit ASCII only
    var result = new Uint8Array(s.length);
    for (var i=0; i<s.length; i++){
        result[i] = s.charCodeAt(i);/* w ww. ja  v  a 2s . co  m*/
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: The mentioned java code in question gives output in the byte[] format. How to achieve that? @Eduard

Comment: I've updated the answer, find `stringToByteArray` function there

Comment: close enough! Just the thing is java byte array elements are in the range of -128 to 127. Thanks.

Comment: use [`TextEncoder`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TextEncoder), which handles byte counts properly for Unicode